# Is it possible to 'Mass Rel=Canonical'?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, canonical-link

I am currently working on an eCommerce WordPress website, with WooCommerce powering the shopping functionality.

At present, the website has the following structure for Products pages:

```
www.example.com/products/product-name/
```

The above structure is generated, regardless of whether a visitor visits directly or via the associated Product Category.

I would like to change this, so that the the Product's URL contains its associated Product Category(ies).  For example:

```
www.example.com/product-category/product-name/
```

Since some Products will fit multiple Product Categories, this approach will inevitably generate duplicate content.  As such, I would need to implement `rel=canonical` as is appropriate, for each Product URL which contains the Product Category, within the URL.  The `rel=canonical` would be 'pointed' towards:

```
www.example.com/products/product-name/
```

Rather than having to implement this to all of the Products manually, is there a way to mass implement the Canonicalisations?

Maybe some kind of PHP Conditional Tag, which 'says':

> If Product is within Product Category, `rel=canonical` to `/products/product-name/`

Or maybe some entry in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Before rending your HTML, you could load it into PHP DOM and add the tags programatically. Otherwise, figure out what part of your application builds the canonical link in the first place, and change its behavior.

Comment: Thanks for this directive.  I have modified the `single-product.php` file to call a `header-shop.php` file rather than the default `header.php`.  In doing so, the `Rel=Canonical` entry will only affect Product pages rather than sitewide.  Is there a resource, which will detail the required Tags, to dynamically generate the relevant URLs?  I want all Category pages to `rel=canonical` to themselves with Product pages `rel=canonical` to their `/products/product-name/` variant.  I assume there would be some kind of conditional logic involved here?